# Segmentation Fault ao remover ocorrências de lista

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

O seguinte código tem o objetivo de remover todas as ocorrências de um dado inteiro numa lista, (listas ligadas), retornando no fim, o numero de elementos retirados.

Dá me o erro de segmentation fault. Agradeço qualquer explicação.

```
typedef struct lligada {
    int valor;
    struct lligada *prox;
} *LInt;

int removeAll (LInt *l, int x){
    int r = 0;
    LInt pt = *l, ant = NULL;
    while (pt != NULL){
        if (pt -> valor == x){
            ant -> prox = pt -> prox;
            pt = pt -> prox;
            r++;
        }
        else {
            ant  = pt;
            pt = pt -> prox;
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: A lista encadeada de itens struct lligada, ao remover uma instância de struct lligada, deve passar o endereço dessa instância para free ()  caso contrário, o resultado é um vazamento de memória

Comment: LInt pt = *; >>>> Llint pt = *l;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem 2 problemas no seu código:

- Não está a fazer `free` dos nós que são removidos, e por isso tem uma fuga de memoria. Este problema apesar de não ser notório pois não lança logo um *segmentation fault*, acaba por deixar o seu programa incorreto, e num caso em que seja utilizado de forma excessiva e continua provavelmente irá manifestar-se.
- Está a aceder ao `ant` sem garantia que ele tenha sido atribuído:

  ```
  LInt pt = *l, ant = NULL; //ant null aqui
  while (pt != NULL){
      if (pt -> valor == x){
          ant -> prox = pt -> prox; //utilizado aqui
  ```

  Repare que se o primeiro nó for para remover, então o `ant` ainda está a `NULL` pois não há nenhum elemento antes desse. Isso faz com que `ant->prox` dê de imediato *segmentation fault*, pois não pode desreferênciar nulo/0.

Para corrigir ambos os problemas poderia reescrever o seu `removeAll` para:

```
int removeAll (LInt *l, int x){
    int r = 0;
    LInt pt = *l, ant = NULL;
    while (pt != NULL){
        if (pt -> valor == x){
            if (ant == NULL){ //se é o primeiro nó
                *l = pt->prox; //avança a cabeça da lista para o seguinte
            }
            else { //senão faz o que já tinha
                ant -> prox = pt -> prox;
            }
            LInt toDelete = pt; //guarda o nó a remover com free
            pt = pt -> prox;
            free(toDelete); //remove o nó que já não é necessário
            r++;
        }
        else {
            ant = pt;
            pt = pt -> prox;
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Qi8zRL)

Answer (score 1):

sugira:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct lligada
{
    int valor;
    struct lligada *next;
};
typedef struct lligada *LInt;

// protótipos
int removeAll (LInt *l, int x);


int removeAll (LInt *l, int x)
{
    int r = 0;
    LInt pt = *l;
    LInt ant = NULL;

    while (pt != NULL)
    {
        if (pt -> valor == x)
        {
            r++;

            ant->next = pt->next->next; 
            free( pt );
        }

        else
        {
            ant = pt;
            pt = pt -> next;
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: agradeço a solução, mas ainda me da segmentation fault.

Comment: então a origem do problema não está no código postado, mas sim no código que cria a lista vinculada.  Meu palpite é que a última entrada na lista tem um próximo valor que não é NULL